# My PUT request only returns the updated values? Node.js Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, put, body-parser

I recently made a PUT request route that works in postman and returns the updated object and shows all the values. But on the client-side in the browser the only the values I updated in post man show up in my react state, all of the other value are undefined.It looks like it is creating a new object with only the values I updated and removing the untouched values.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCLmZ.png) What could be causing this issue?

[image]

[image]

server-side route

```
router.put('/api/house-details/:id', (req, res) => {
    const options = { new: true };
    console.log(req.body)
    House.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, options).exec().then((data)=>{
        console.log(req.body)
        if (data.value === null) {
           return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{location: "house-details", msg: "Not found", param: req.params.id}]})
        }
        return res.status(200).json(data)
    }).catch((error)=>{
        return res.status(500).json({"error": error})
    })
});
```

models

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const HouseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    house_location: {
        city:{type:String, required: true},
        county:{type:String, required: true},
        us_state: {type: String, required: true}
    },

    house_details: {
        squarefeet:{type: Number, required: true},
        price: { type: Number, required: true},
        isSaleOrRent: {type: String, required: true},
        numOfBeds: {type: Number, required: true},
        numOfBaths: {type: Number, required: true},
        numOfGarages: { type: Number, required: true},
        house_image: {type: String, required: true}
    }
});


const House = mongoose.model("House", HouseSchema);
module.exports = {House}
```

Comment: By the sounds of it, it seems like the issue is with the React implementation and not your API. Probably want to share snippets from how you are handling the API response in React.

Comment: I was thinking that but I haven't even implemented the api response in React yet. I noticed that when I make my PUT request in postman for a value in either `house_details` or `house_location`  the response only returns the updated values and gets rid of the other values.